# SQL Query to Split a string, format each result, then build back into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been working on a rather convoluted process to format some data for a work project. We received a data extract and need to export it for import during a migration, but some of the data won't import due to case sensitivity (user logons with sentence case for example).

In an ideal world, I could demand the data be sanitised and formatted before it's provided for me to build the import, but I can't, so I'm stuck where I have to format it myself.

**Plan:**

- Take string result
- Split string result by pipe delimitation
- Format each split results `( )` into lower case (where applicable)
- Put all split results back into one string using FOR XML PATH

**Example of problem:**

Field 'Assigned To' can contain a pipe delimitted string of users and/or user groups, e.g.

```
John Smith (jsmith)|College Group of Arts|Bob Jones (BJones)
```

Now as you can see above, John Smith (jsmith) looks fine, as does College Group of Arts, however Bob Jones has had his logon sentence cased, so I need to use a LOWER command, chained with SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX to convert the logon to lower. Standalone, this approach works fine, but the problem I'm having is where I'm using a function found here on Stack Overflow (slightly manipulated to account for pipe delimitation) [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string).

When I retrieve the table results of the split string, I can't apply CHARINDEX against any characters in the result string, and I can't work out why.

**Scenario:**

The raw data extract, untouched, returns the below when queried;

```
|College of Science Administrators|Bob Jones (BJones)|
```

I then apply the below query, which calls the function queried above;

```
declare @assignedto nvarchar(max) = (select assigned_to from project where project_id = 1234)

SELECT SUBSTRING(Name,CHARINDEX(Name,'('),255)

FROM dbo.splitstring(@assignedto)
```

I then get the below results;

```
College of Science Administrators
Bob Jones (BJones)
```

What I'd **expect** to see is;

```
College of Science Administrators
(BJones)
```

I could then apply my LOWER logic to change it to lower case.

If that worked, then thought process was then to take those results and pass them back into a single string using a FOR XML PATH.

So I guess technically, there are 2 questions here;

- Why won't my function let me manipulate the results with CHARINDEX?
- And is this the best way to do what I'm trying to achieve overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you take that splitstring function you found and throw it away. It is horribly inefficient and doesn't even take the delimiter as a parameter. There are so many better splitter options available. One such example is the DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD which can be found [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

I noticed you also have your delimiters at the beginning and the end so you have to eliminate those but not a big deal. Here is how I would go about parsing this string. I am using a variable for your string here with the value you said is in your table.

```
declare @Something varchar(100) = '|College of Science Administrators|Bob Jones (BJones)|'

select MyOutput = case when charindex('(', x.Item) > 1 then substring(x.Item, charindex('(', x.Item), len(x.Item)) else Item end
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@Something, '|') x
where x.Item > ''
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a whirl. It's the second organisation I've worked for where they don't use SQL Server 2017, so I've not been able to utilise the STRING_SPLIT function which would make my life so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

For question #1 you must simply invert parameters in CharIndex :

```
CHARINDEX('(', Name))
```

Comment: Whoops - I've used this function hundreds of times before, my bad, thanks!